# PHP Change default User on fopen

Tags: php, permissions, fopen, symfony5, symfony-filesystem

I'm having problems when trying to write a file with a different user rather than www-data.
I need to leave the file on a mapped unit that it's NOT mine so i cannot change permissions on that one. Insetead i have a username and a group, let's call them 'myself':'myself'

I'm using Symfony 5 Filesystem to move files around but i still use PHP's fopen to create those files. This is what i have so far.

```
private function moveAndDeleteFile($url_origin, $url_destiny)
{
    $filesystem = new Filesystem();

    $a = fopen($url_origin, 'wa+');
    fwrite($a, 'Test');
    fclose($a);

    $filesystem->copy($url_origin, $url_destino, true);

    if (!$filesystem->exists($url_destiny)) {
        return false;
    }
    $filesystem->remove($url_origin);

    return true;
}
```

This is just a test, so i'm creating a file (name included in $url_origin) and try to copy the file to $url_destiny and then remove the original (again, just a test).

The ting is that the file is always created by www-data and for my target directory i need to set the file owner to 'myself'.

Is there any way i can change the file owner with sudo?

```
$filesystem->chown($url_origin, 'myself', false);
```

This returns an error -> Failed to chown file "my/route/file.xml"

Same thing happens when trying

```
$filesystem->chgrp($url_origin, 'myself', false);
```

Then i tried to use the default PHP chown() function like this:

```
chown($url_origin, 'myself');
```

And get this other Error:  Operation not permitted.

I guess that i need to specify somewhere the user's properties but i'm clueless right now. Any ideas on how to pass this through? i'm sure i'm missing something obvious.

Thanks-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use "chown" because only "root" can use "chown".

The way is to set "chmod" or change configuration in your server with php-fpm running with myself user.

Regards